# ssh but keep current working directory

Tags: linux, ssh, unix

I often want to ssh into a different server, but retain my working directory. (All our servers have the same NFS and thus the same directory path usually exists on all servers.) Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 3):

I personally don't like to `alias ssh`.
The fewest number of characters I found to do the job is :

```
ssh user@hostname -t "cd $PWD;bash"
```

Answer (score 2):

If the remote server has been preconfigured (in sshd_config) with

```
AcceptEnv CURRENT_DIR
```

And you include

```
cd "$CURRENT_DIR"
```

as the last line in the remote servers' ~/.bashrc, you can connect with

```
CURRENT_DIR="$PWD" ssh user@host -o SendEnv=CURRENT_DIR
```

It's a workaround, but it'll...work.

Answer (score 2):

I found a nice solution on [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/a/46888/14113) which is much like @adaptr's solution but without manually setting the environment variable.

By creating an alias for `ssh` you can set that variable automatically:

```
alias ssh='env SSH_PWD="$PWD" /bin/ssh'
```

Configure ssh in `~/.ssh/config` to send the `SSH_PWD` variable:

For a single host add this:

```
Host myhost
  SendEnv SSH_PWD
```

Or for all hosts add this to the bottom of the file:

```
SendEnv SSH_PWD
```

And on the remote server in your `.profile` or `.bashrc`:

```
if [ -n "$SSH_PWD" ] && [ -d "$SSH_PWD" ]; then
   cd "$SSH_PWD"
   unset SSH_PWD
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change the remote servers's configuration and use key-based SSH logins with an `ssh-agent` (thus sparing you to have to enter your password or key passphrase every time), another hackish approach:

On your local machine, create a wrapper script which is in your path (eg. `/usr/local/bin/cdssh`)

```
#!/bin/bash
TMPFILE="/tmp/$(basename $0).$$.tmp"
echo "cd `pwd`" > $TMPFILE
scp -q $TMPFILE $1:~/.cwdfile
ssh $@
rm $TMPFILE
```

On the remote machine, add the following part to your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile`:

```
if [ -f ~/.cwdfile ]; then
   cd ~/.cwdfile
   rm ~/.cwdfile
fi
```

Obviously, this is a  wild hack, but it works.